# Extract subfolder name from path string

Tags: string, powershell, extract

I'm putting together a PowerShell script to copy files from one location to another:

It needs to extract the home folder name "12345" as this will be used to create a subfolder in the destination before we drop a copy of the in it.
Source: C:\users\bingo\12345\filesname.txt

Destination: D:\archive\12345\filesname.txt

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regex is unnecessary for this when `-split`/`Split()` will do, but you don't even need that.  If `$file` is a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` then `$file.Directory.Name` is the name of its parent directory and `$file.DirectoryName` is the path of its parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this...

```
((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\pdf\AR-01-11 - file name_.pdf').Directory).Name
# Results
<#
pdf
#>

((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\pdf\AR-01-11 - file name_.pdf').Directory).FullName
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\pdf
#>
```

Or this...

```
((Get-ItemProperty -Path 'D:\Temp\pdf\AR-01-11 - file name_.pdf').Directory).Name
# Results
<#
ItemProperty
#>


((Get-ItemProperty -Path 'D:\Temp\pdf\AR-01-11 - file name_.pdf').Directory).FullName
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\pdf
#>
```